# Removing the upper bound for a summation

Tags: statistics, discrete-mathematics, summation

I going over a chapter in my book for discrete mathematics and there is the following rewrite of a summation.
They present

$$\ell_{n}=\sum_{i=0}^{n / 2-1} \ell_{2 i} \ell_{n-2 i-2} $$
and state that it is valid in this case for even values of n≥2. Then they say that we can simplify it by rewriting it as

$$
\begin{array}{c}{\ell_{n}=\sum_{k \geq 0} \ell_{k} \ell_{n-k-2}} \\ {\ell_{n}=\sum_{k \geq 0} \ell_{k} \ell_{n-k-2}+[n=0]}\end{array}
$$
And i just dont quite understand how they do this?

Comment: What are "equal values of $n\geq2$?"  Did you mean "even values"?

Comment: @saulspatz yes, my mistake.